# error when deploying my smart contract

Tags: smart-contracts, error, ligo, deploy

I created a smart contract it compiles without problem but I have an error when deploying, I don't know what this error can refer to...

```
HttpResponse: Http error response: (500) [{"kind":"temporary","id":"failure","msg":"Error while applying operation ood21FLzwWRzrbUQkCESDNJeL9zodNAAQ8AYLWwxetRTPuBB59e:\nbranch refused (Error:\n                  Counter 3333097 already used for contract tz1i3veHnR4ogcwKmgugcqnunTmTYP8s8ZAr (expected 3333098)\n)"}]

    at XMLHttpRequest.request.onload (M:\TEZOS\DEV\TEZOS_NFT_V2\node_modules\@taquito\http-utils\src\taquito-http-utils.ts:132:13)
    at XMLHttpRequestEventTarget.dispatchEvent (M:\TEZOS\DEV\TEZOS_NFT_V2\node_modules\xhr2-cookies\xml-http-request-event-target.ts:44:13)
    at XMLHttpRequest._dispatchProgress (M:\TEZOS\DEV\TEZOS_NFT_V2\node_modules\xhr2-cookies\xml-http-request.ts:390:8)
    at XMLHttpRequest._onHttpResponseEnd (M:\TEZOS\DEV\TEZOS_NFT_V2\node_modules\xhr2-cookies\xml-http-request.ts:347:8)
    at IncomingMessage.<anonymous> (M:\TEZOS\DEV\TEZOS_NFT_V2\node_modules\xhr2-cookies\xml-http-request.ts:311:39)
    at IncomingMessage.emit (node:events:532:35)
    at IncomingMessage.emit (node:domain:475:12)
    at endReadableNT (node:internal/streams/readable:1346:12)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:83:21) {
  status: 500,
  statusText: 'Internal Server Error',
  body: '[{"kind":"temporary","id":"failure","msg":"Error while applying operation ood21FLzwWRzrbUQkCESDNJeL9zodNAAQ8AYLWwxetRTPuBB59e:\\nbranch refused (Error:\\n                  Counter 3333097 already used for contract tz1i3veHnR4ogcwKmgugcqnunTmTYP8s8ZAr (expected 3333098)\\n)"}]\n',
  url: 'https://rpc.hangzhou.tzstats.com/injection/operation'
```

my deploy:

```
import { TezosToolkit } from '@taquito/taquito'
import { importKey } from '@taquito/signer'
import * as fs from 'fs';

const provider = 'https://rpc.hangzhou.tzstats.com'

async function deploy() {
  const tezos = new TezosToolkit(provider)
  await importKey(
    tezos,
    'hpdcsnao.ixquxooo@teztnets.xyz', //mail
    'ZSrbDk3Nzf', //password
    [
        "sky",
        "inquiry",
        "build",
        "man",
        "aunt",
        "tropic",
        "pattern",
        "image",
        "giant",
        "burger",
        "shock",
        "banner",
        "safe",
        "initial",
        "rather"
    ].join(' '),
    '121124d38edd019ec3d8c2ad91d562599efea920' //private key
  )

  try {
    const op = await tezos.contract.originate({
      //smart contract code
      code: JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync("./nft.json").toString()),
      //storage state
      init: '(Pair (Pair (Pair "tz1i3veHnR4ogcwKmgugcqnunTmTYP8s8ZAr" { Elt 1 "tz1i3veHnR4ogcwKmgugcqnunTmTYP8s8ZAr" }) (Pair { Elt "" 0x68747470733a2f2f676973742e67697468756275736572636f6e74656e742e636f6d2f6f7269616e6131332f36663138333737353065366562383163646434666633363230663738613133322f7261772f653238396663353037326235613931353134383936376239613433333765313835343731363561322f636f6e74726163745f6d6574612e6a736f6e } 2)) (Pair (Pair {  } { Elt "tz1i3veHnR4ogcwKmgugcqnunTmTYP8s8ZAr" { 1 } }) { Elt 1 (Pair 1 { Elt "" 0x68747470733a2f2f676973742e67697468756275736572636f6e74656e742e636f6d2f6f7269616e6131332f35313763373231396531383639333938613765666631343335623862653237392f7261772f326337336132613564353365626466313662633864623831643837343236353964323763646462332f6e66745f6d6574612e6a736f6e }) }))'
    })
    //beginning to deploy
    console.log('Awaiting confirmation...')
    const contract = await op.contract()
    //deployment report: amount of used gas, storage state
    console.log('Gas Used', op.consumedGas)
    console.log('Storage', await contract.storage())
    //operation hash one can use to find the contract in the explorer
    console.log('Operation hash:', op.hash)
  } catch (ex) {
    console.error(ex)
  }
}

deploy()
```

thank you all for your help and attention

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that you already have an operation pending in the mempool. Restarting the node or waiting for 60 blocks should fix the error.

I think that in the Ithaca testnet you can now replace an operation by increasing the fee.

Comment: I am on test net hangzhounet how to solve this problem exactly (I am new to tezos) I updated my question with my deploy file, the weird thing is yesterday it was working and all of a sudden nothing I don't think I have an operation pending...

Comment: my error is corrected, hangzhounet changed rpc it is no longer: https://rpc.hangzhou.tzstats.com but now: https://rpc.tzkt.io/hangzhou2net :)

Comment: More backup nodes: https://visualtez.com/nodes